# Edit class from imported module

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following problem. I want to edit the variables of the class from the module I just imported. I can only find the reverse way. To edit module from main.
I want the following:

#### main.py:

```
class A:
     MyVar = 7
import a
print(MyVar) #I want to get 4
```

#### a.py:

```
 A.MyVar = 4
```

When executing main.py I get 'NameError: name A is not defined'.

Comment: `A` is not in `a.py`'s namespace.

Comment: Not in main's namespace? Then how can I add it there?

Comment: You are going to encounter other problems in this situation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should do something like this:

#### main.py:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    from a import A

    print(A.my_var) # 7

    A.my_var = 4

    print(A.my_var) # 4
```

#### a.py:

```
class A(object):
    my_var = 7
```

or

#### main.py:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    from a import A

    a_obj = A()

    print(a_obj.my_var) # 7

    a_obj.my_var = 4

    print(a_obj.my_var) # 4
```

#### a.py:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.my_var = 7
```

Comment: Exactly: keep separate the code that *defines* `A`, and the code that *uses* `A`.